# A contradiction statement to $F=ma$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

If I thrown an object of mass 1 kg up in the air it will always fall with an acceleration of 9.8m/s. If I throw it very high up in the sky, it falls with a greater force as compared to if i throw it just a meter high. But according to $F=ma$ formula the force should be the same isn't as the mass is the same as well as the acceleration is same, so why do we feel a greater force if the height is increased?
(I think that this is because the mass is gradually increasing with the increase in speed, because according to the theory of relativity mass increases with speed. Is that right?)

Comment: *"it falls with a greater force"*...what does that mean? The force/acceleration acting on the rock is always the same, namely that of gravity.

Comment: Perhaps he is confusing the force acting on the object with the momentum transfer (oomph) upon trying to catch it?

Comment: The force in $F=ma$ is the force *on* the object, not the force beign done *by* the object. In other words, it always feels the same gravitational force, but if you throw it higher it will come back down faster and the force exerted on your head will be bigger.

Comment: You confuse force with velocity (or momentum which is mass times velocity). An object falls and touches the ground with a certain velocity, which is higher if you throw it higher. It achieved this high velocity by the constant acceleration of 9.8m/s^2. The higher you throw it, the more time it gets to accelerate before it touches the ground and hence, the higher its velocity.

Comment: *If I throw it very high up in the sky, it falls with a greater force as compared to if i throw it just a meter high.* is obviously false given the previous statement of *it will always fall with an acceleration of 9.8 m/s/s* (units fixed for correctness here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your logic, there is no gravitational force on the ball while you are holding it, because it is not accelerating. And if there is no gravitational force you should be able to throw the ball as high as you want, right? The truth, though, is that there are two forces on the ball - one from your hand and one from gravity - which are in balance. Keeping that in mind, consider that it is the *net* force that changes in all the following:

When you throw the ball upwards, you accelerate it (i.e. change its velocity) with your hand. When you catch the ball, you accelerate it with your hand. To throw it higher, you must apply a greater force, which results in a greater acceleration, meaning a higher initial velocity and thus a higher trajectory. Then, gravity has more time (or distance, if you prefer) over which to act on the ball, so when the ball is thrown higher, it also lands harder; that is, with more momentum.

Let's simplify the situation, though: we'll take gravity out of the picture by having you throw the ball to a friend a few meters away. If you throw the ball gently (I.e. apply little force to it) then your friend can catch it gently, because it has a low velocity and little acceleration is needed to stop it. If you throw the ball with great force, it accelerates greatly and has a large velocity; your friend must apply a large force (a large acceleration) to stop it. And because there is an equal and opposite reaction, the ball applies a large force to your friend as well, which can *really hurt.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the paradox you are describing and i have some issues with your text:

1. "*it will always fall with an acceleration of 9.8m/s*": If there is air resistance, it will reach a terminal velocity at which the object is no longer accelerating. Let's assume no air resistance to make things easy.
2. "*If I throw it very high up in the sky, it falls with a greater force as compared to if i throw it just a meter high*": There is no distance dependence of the force, like you say the only force on the object is $F=mg$. Regardless of height, for a constant mass and gravitational acceleration, the force is the same.
3. "*so why do we feel a greater force if the height is increased?*": I don't understand this point, but to me it seems you are saying that it requires more force to throw it higher? This is correct as a higher initial velocity is required to increase the vertical distance traveled. The higher initial velocity is generated by applying more force on the object by your hands before letting go. However, at the point you let go of the object, the force balance reduces only to $F=mg$ as before. If you mean that upon catching the object the force is greater, this is due to the rate of change in momentum due to deceleration to rest. The force is given roughly by $F=\Delta(mv)/\Delta t$ and assuming it takes roughly the same amount of time to decelerate the object from different heights, the object with the highest final speed will have the highest impact force.
4. "*... theory of relativity ...*": Goodluck throwing your object fast enough for this to apply without it being negligible.

Answer (score 0):

For one constant acceleration $a_{\mathrm{Gravitation}}$ is an approximation, that holds because the radius of the earth is so big compared to the height of your thrown mass.

That being said, what you probably "feel" is, that something with greater height gains more momentum on his way back to the ground (as the distance is greater so is the time needed to reach the ground).

If you really want to know about the effect of the force changing with height, you should look into the gravitation potential of the earth.

Answer (score 0):

While your object is in motion its acceleration is $g$, or -9.81 m/sec$^2$ (we'll take the upwards direction to be positive). This constant acceleration is why the velocity decreases from its initial value of $+v$ when you throw it to $-v$ when it lands. So far so good.

But I think the force you are talking about is the force required to stop the object when it lands e.g. the force you feel if it hits you on the head. Suppose the object takes a distance $d$ to stop, i.e. it makes a dent in your head of depth $d$, then the acceleration required to stop it is given by:

$$ a = \frac{v^2}{2d} $$

And the velocity $v$ is just the velocity that you threw it upwards. The gravitational acceleration doesn't appear in the equation all. If you did the experiment on the Moon or on Jupiter then if you threw the object upwards at the same speed $v$ it would hurt just the same when it hit you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a 1 kg object that you want to throw directly upward and have it reach a height of 1 meter *after* you let go of it. Using 
$$2a(y -y_o)=v^2-v_o^2$$ with a constant acceleration of $a=-g=-9.80 m/s^2$ (up is my choice of positive direction) we get that $v_0= \pm 4.43 $ m/s. We choose the positive solution. That means my hand must exert an upward force on the object to accelerate it from 0 to 4.43 m/s upward. If I do that in 0.5 seconds, I must cause an average upward acceleration of 8.86 m/s$^2$ on the rock.

Two forces are acting on the rock: my hand upward and Earth's gravitational pull downward. Newton's 2nd Law says:
$$\vec{F}_{hand}+\vec{F}_{Earth}=m\vec{a},$$
$$\vec{F}_{hand}+mg(-\hat{j})=m(8.86)(+\hat{j}),$$
$$\vec{F}_{hand}=m(9.80+8.86)(+\hat{j}).$$

My hand must exert a force of 18.7 N to make this happen. If I want to throw the object higher, I must provide a larger upward initial velocity which requires a larger upward acceleration and a larger force *from my hand*.

The same logic works in reverse with this object falling from differing heights. The hand must exert a larger force upward on the rock to stop it when falling from a higher starting point.

You should also consider the time interval.  If you want to stop an object in a shorter time, your hand must exert a larger force even if the starting height is the same.

$$m(\vec{v}_{2}-\vec{v}_{1})=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\vec{F}(t)\,dt=\vec{F}_{ave}(t_2-t_1)$$

Answer (score 0):

The force that you "feel" is not just the **current** force of gravity but the **sum effect** of lots of gravitational force.

There are a couple equivalent ways to sum up the forces involved. One is called "impulse" and "momentum". This says that when a (constant) force acts on an object for a unit of time, it gets an "impulse" equal to the product of the two. So the gravitational force is a constant, $F = -m~g$, but when it acts for a unit of time $T$ then it produces the impulse $-m~g~T$. You, meanwhile, give this thing two impulses, the first one being $F~t$ to get it going upwards, where $t$ is the time you take to throw it and $F$ is the force you use to do so, and again $F t$ to stop it when it is coming downwards. The total momentum change ends up being zero, so $2~F~t - m~g~T = 0$. The reason that the force $F$ you feel is greater is because $T/t$ is greater.

A long time ago we realized that this math was a little inconvenient, and it is more convenient is "work" and "energy". This says that when a (constant) force acts on an object for a unit of distance, it does a "work" equal to the product of the two times the cosine of the angle between them. This cosine could be $+1$ if your force is in the direction of your motion or $-1$ if it is against it. Again the gravitational force is a constant, $F = -m~g$, but when it acts over the distance $H$, where $H$ is the maximum height we attain, then it produces the work $- m~g~H$, but on the way down, it produces the work $+m~g~H$. So the net work of the gravitational force is always zero if you come back to the same height. However, given your force $F$ acting over the distance $d$ that your hands throw upwards (about one meter), the work that you do with your hand is $F~d$ when you start and $-F~d$ when you finish, bringing it back to zero energy.

One reason that this is incredibly convenient is that, classically speaking, the work generates a change in *kinetic energy* $\frac 12 m (v_1^2 - v_0^2)$.

It turns out that your gut instinct that this somehow has to do with "increased mass" due to relativity is actually (against all odds) **totally correct**: the relativistic mass-energy turns out to be $E = m c^2 / \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}$, which for speeds $v \ll c$ (where $c$ is the speed of light) works out to be $$E \approx m~c^2 + \frac 12~m~v^2.$$There are a couple of ways to look at this, and the most simple is **not** the one that you gave, but rather looks like, "I have to do this work to dump this kinetic energy into this object: but energy is also a form of mass, so the thing gets a very tiny bit more massive and heavier." But you can certainly view it consequentially, saying "I have to get it moving so I have to increase its apparent mass so I have to dump this energy into it," if you want to.